# How to scrape all data from this site using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to web scraping. I want to scrape data from [here](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=NY.GDP.MKTP.CD&country=#), mainly the data on the right which has the year, country and GDP of the countries.

My code is as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = "http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=NY.GDP.MKTP.CD&country=#"
page = urlopen(data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('div',attrs = {'class':'canvas'})
name = name_box.text.strip()

print(name)
```

I can obtain the data however it is only those at the top 10+.

So my question would be how do I do it for problems like these when the data are not on the page itself (i.e it was imported from elsewhere). 
Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: search for javascript rendering, check the requests with chrome developer tools, or use selenium

Comment: (1) There's a blank in the URL you're attempting to open. (2) What data are you attempting to receive?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, this is the site : http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=2&series=NY.GDP.MKTP.CD&country=#   otherwise you could click 'here' in the question.

Comment: Use Selenium: scroll that table to the bottom a couple of times and then extract generated html to bs4

Comment: Scrolling it doesn't help, it still printed out 'loading' after 10+ of them are out.

Answer (score 2):

When I visit the link, there is a whole menu dedicated to "Download Options." Why not just use that?

Comment: I wish I could but this is my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, when javascript loads more data it makes a call to an endpoint.

When you call `urlopen(data)` you are making a call to an endpoint.  Similar calls are made in newer versions of python using `requests.get(data)` or `requests.post(data)`.  The documentation for [urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) has extensive examples and uses.  If you look at the request the javascript is making it has many parts(headers, parameters, method, etc.).  You can add these parts to your request in urlopen in order to copy(mimic) the call that the javascript is making.

If you can mimic that call then you would load the data from the subsequent call into your soup.  Then you can parse the data.

If you cannot mimic that call, then your best bet would be to use some sort of headless browser.  A couple of the most used are Dryscrape and Selenium.  I personally prefer [Dryscrape](http://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Looking at the comments on your question I see you are already using selenium.  Similarly to the scroll, when that scroll is done it usually makes the subsequent calls I mentioned before.  If you can mimic them in their entirety(headers, params, qwargs, etc.), then you can get your browser to load the data.